# How to set all heading sizes with Koma-Script "disposition"?

Tags: sectioning, koma-script, fontsize

I can change all heading sizes one by one with `addtokomafont` or `setkomafont`; however, if I try to set a global heading size with `disposition` or 
`\RedeclareSectionCommands`, it doesn't work.

Is it possible to set all heading sizes with Koma-Script "disposition"?

```
\documentclass[footsepline=true]{scrbook}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[sfdefault,lf]{FiraSans}

\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\clearscrheadfoot
\ihead{\headmark}
\ohead{\pagemark}

\setkomafont{footsepline}{\color{orange}}

\renewcommand*{\chapterpagestyle}{scrheadings}

\RedeclareSectionCommands
[beforeskip=\baselineskip, afterskip=\baselineskip]
{part,chapter,section,subsection,paragraph,subparagraph}
% setting font=\normalsize here makes no difference either

\setkomafont{chapter}{\bfseries\color{yellow}\normalsize} %different color just for testing

\addtokomafont{disposition}{\normalsize} % makes no difference



\begin{document}

\chapter{title} 
\section{title} 

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my system, using this in in the `\RedeclareSectionCommands` worked:

```
[beforeskip=\baselineskip, afterskip=\baselineskip, font=\normalsize]
```

It reduced the font size to 11 pt. I am running an updated MikTeX system under Win7. From the .LOG-file.

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (MiKTeX 2.9.7250)
entering extended mode
(C:/temp/test-koma-disposition-fontsize.tex
LaTeX2e <2019-10-01> patch level 3
(C:\miktex\texmfs\install\tex/latex/koma-script\scrbook.cls
Document Class: scrbook 2019/10/12 v3.27 KOMA-Script document class (book)
```

Using `\setkomafont{disposition}{\normalsize}` removes the bold from the heading on my system, but does not reduce the font size, as it should do. However, at page 103 in the manual, it is written:

> You can change the font style for all headings with the \setkomafont and \addtokomafont commands (see section 3.6, page 60). In doing so, the element disposition is applied first, followed by the specific element for each sectioning level (see table 3.2, page 61). There is a separate elements, partnumber, for the number of the part heading, and chapterprefix, for the optional prefix line of chapter headings. The initial definition for the disposition element is \normalcolor\sffamily\bfseries. The default font sizes for the specific elements
>   depends on the options headings=big, headings=normal, and headings=small (see page 97). They are listed in table 3.15.

Maybe the font size set in the definition of the chapter and section is defined in a way that they override the redefinition you do by `\setkomafont{dispositon}` because they are *after* the content of the `disposition`.  I am not sure and cannot find such behaviour documented. It looks more as a bug.

[image]

```
\documentclass[footsepline=true]{scrbook}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[sfdefault,lf]{FiraSans}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\clearscrheadfoot
\ihead{\headmark}
\ohead{\pagemark}

\renewcommand*{\chapterpagestyle}{scrheadings}

\RedeclareSectionCommands
[beforeskip=\baselineskip, afterskip=\baselineskip, font=\normalsize]
{part,chapter,section,subsection,paragraph,subparagraph}

\setkomafont{chapter}{\bfseries\color{yellow}} %different color just for testing

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter title} 
\section{Section title}

Text for a story or two. 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Sveinung, it's weird, but now it works. `\setkomafont{disposition}{\normalsize}` still doesn't work, though, but that's not a problem. Thanks.

Comment: @Joseph I confirm that `\setkomafont{disposition}{\normalsize} ` does not work on my system.